# Grab datetime from HTML5 Time Object (not just in Firefox)

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

The following code will output **string** in Firefox and **undefined** in every other browser.

```js
document.getElementById('output').textContent = typeof document.getElementsByTagName('time')[0].dateTime
```

```html
<time datetime="2008-02-14 20:00">Time</time>
<br/>Output: <b><span id="output"></span></b>
```

As [w3schools shows](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_time_datetime.asp), this is because only Firefox supports the dateTime property.

So how can <time> still be read in JS in other browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this

```js
document.querySelector('#output').textContent = document.querySelector('time').getAttribute("datetime");

console.log(document.querySelector('time').getAttribute("datetime"));
```

```html
<time datetime="2008-02-14 20:00">Time</time>
<br/>Output: <b><span id="output"></span></b>
```

Comment: Great answer. Clear, precise and allows running the code. Tell me: is there any reason at all to give Firefox a special treatment, if it supports this way anyway?

Answer (score 2):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time), the `<time>` tag is not supported only in firefox, but also in chrome (>=62) and edge, but you do have problems with all IE versions.

If the only thing you need is to take that time and display it in some other element in your DOM, there is no really need for that code. You can just use:

```
document.getElementById('output').textContent = '2008-02-14 20:00';
```

Regarding your code, remove the `typeof` you have there, and if you need the value of the `datetime` attribute, you can use `getAttribute('datetime')` - it should work in other browsers as well.

Comment: Yes, but please note I wrote "only Firefox supports the **dateTime** property".

Comment: That property **is** supported on the `time` element in all browsers, however you can access it directly **only** on firefox.

Comment: I keep referring to [the dateTime Property](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_time_datetime.asp), while I believe you refer to [the datetime attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_time_datetime.asp).

Comment: got what you were looking for :)